# How to retrieve the int value of a selected item in a spinner?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, spinner

I'm making a relational database app in for android that displays an invoice based on the selected id I have used to populate a spinner. The spinner populates correctly, but I need to get the integer value of the id(not the index of the spinner) for the parameter of the `viewInvoice` method that holds the SQL. I have tried using the `getSelectedItem` method, but that doesn't seem to do what I need.

Here is the code for the spinner:

```
package com.example.dh0020348.inventory;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewAllCustomers extends AppCompatActivity {
DbHelper db;
TextView id, name, email, address, city, state, zip, phone, invoiceID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_customers);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    db = new DbHelper(this);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerInvoiceID);

    DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(ViewAllCustomers.this);
    String[] spinnerLists = dbBackend.getAllSpinnerContent();

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewAllCustomers.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerLists);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            double total;
            Cursor res = db.viewInvoice(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem())));
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                // show message
                showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            buffer.append("Invoice ID: " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Date: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Name: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Street Address: " + res.getString(8) + "\n");
            buffer.append("City: " + res.getString(9) + "\n");
            buffer.append("State: " + res.getString(10) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Zip Code: " + res.getString(11) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Phone: " + res.getString(12) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Item: " + res.getString(4) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Size: " + res.getString(5) + "\n");
            buffer.append(String.format("Price Per Item: %.2f", Double.parseDouble(res.getString(7))) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Quantity: " + res.getString(6) + "\n");
            total = Double.parseDouble(res.getString(7)) * Double.parseDouble(res.getString(6));
            buffer.append(String.format("Total Price: %.2f", total));

            // show all data
            showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCustomerID);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCustomerName);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCustomerEmail);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCustomerAddress);
    city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCity);
    state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblState);
    zip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblZip);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblPhone);
    invoiceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblInvoice);

    ViewAllCustomers();
//        ViewCustomerInvoices();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

//display the StringBuffer message
public void showMessage(String title, String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}

public void ViewAllCustomers(){

    Cursor res = db.viewAllCustomers();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        id.setText("ID: " + res.getString(0));
        name.setText("Name: " + res.getString(1));
        email.setText("Email: " + res.getString(2));
        address.setText("Address: " + res.getString(3));
        city.setText("City: " + res.getString(4));
        state.setText("State: " + res.getString(5));
        zip.setText("Zip: " + res.getString(6));
        phone.setText("Phone: " + res.getString(7));
        invoiceID.setText("Invoice ID:");
    }
}
}
```

And here is the method with the query in my `DbHelper` class:

```
 //view a single saved invoice
public Cursor viewInvoice(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT ord." + INVOICE_ID + ", " + INVOICE_DATE + ", " + C_CUSTOMER_NAME + ", cus."
            + C_CUSTOMER_ID + ", inventory." + INVENTORY_ITEM + ", " + ORDERED_SIZE + ", " + ORDERED_QUANTITY + ", "
            + INVENTORY_PRICE + ", " + C_STREET_ADDRESS + ", " + C_CITY + ", " + C_STATE +
            ", " + C_ZIP + ", " + C_PHONE +
            " FROM " + TABLE_INVOICE + " as inv INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CUSTOMER + " as cus " +
            "ON inv." + C_CUSTOMER_ID + " = " + "cus." + C_CUSTOMER_ID +
            " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_ORDERED + " as ord ON inv." + INVOICE_ID + " = " + "ord." + ORDERED_ID +
            " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_INVENTORY + " as inventory " +
            "ON ord." + INVENTORY_ID + " = " + " inventory." + INVENTORY_ID, null);
    if(res != null)
        res.moveToFirst();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you constructing the query like that...?

Comment: Sorry I should have included in my displayed code. I have a lot of constants that I use to create the tables. Is this poor form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Then cast it to whatever object you have populated it with.

Comment: This works to display the first index of the spinner, but does not change when I select another index.

Comment: Then use "position" parameter from onItemSelected method as an index of item from that spinner.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to use the position parameter as the parameter of the getSelectedItem method? because this method does not accept a parameter. Or perhaps I can use the getSelectedItemPosition method and somehow pull the value from there?

Comment: onItemSelected() callback gives you "position" (3rd parameter) when you select something from the spinner. You take that number and use it as an index to search the item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spinnerAdapter.getSelectedItemId()`, it'll return currently selected item ID or `INVALID_ROW_ID` (-9223372036854775808) if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways ,

1] using spinner item position ,

```
int myNum = 0;

    try {
        myNum = Integer.parseInt(Spinner_NAME.get(position).toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
       Log.e("","Exception :: "+nfe);
    }
```

2] If you are using any model class or any arraylist then,

```
int myNum = Integer.parseInt(spinner1.getModel().getValue().toString());
```